# setTimeout in node.js - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, settimeout, pug

Here I have a code for sum 3 numbers i+j+k but I waht to know how to configure server file to work with setTimeout function... is there some restriction?

so, here is mycode:

index.jade

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title Test
  body
    form(name='form1', method='post', action='')
      label(for='1')
      input#1(type='text', name='1')
      label(for='2')
      input#2(type='text', name='2')
      label(for='3')
      input#3(type='text', name='3')
      input(name='submit', type='button', value='submit') 
    span #{result}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
        app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set("view options", { layout: false });
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        var result;
    res.render('index', {result: ''});
});


    app.post('/', function(req, res){
      var i = req.param('1', 0);
      i = parseInt(i);
      var j = req.param('2', 0);
          j = parseInt(j);

      var k = req.param('3', 0);
         k = parseInt(k);

      var r = i+j+k;
      res.render('index', {result:r});

    });
app.listen(3010);
```

How etc. to block user action (click,doubleclick,rightclick) and show him a div with text "You can do any action" in first 5 seconds and after that user can do action but after 60 seconds again can't do any action... Can I do this with setTimout function or HOW???

sorry for my english

Comment: that easy with javascript on clientside but I need to to with server control user so I need to write that function on serverside file app.js, Can i use setTimeot or???

Comment: `click`, `doubleclick`, `rightclick` and such events only happen in the client side. The server side gets events like a new incoming request. While you can use `setTimeout` on the server side, that doesn't really change anything.

Comment: ok, but is a good solution to show I some div that will cover all screen 5s and then dissaper... so on css i will have a width:100%, height:100% and How I can change visibility on time etc. after 5s... so when 5s over then I change visibility:visible ... or hidden after some time???

Comment: when I cover screen with DIV 100% users can't do anything? :)

Comment: Yes they can (with some computer savviness), but you can simply refuse to serve them on the server side if it was less than 60 seconds since last request for example...

Comment: only what I need is to send a request from server to clinet to change css settings after 5s. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this on the server side. You have to insert a client side javascript that blocks the interaction and unblocks it again after 5 sec.

The code for doing this on the client side would be something like this:

```
// this code should be executed when the client receives a message from the server.
var overlay = document.getElementById("your-element-id");
overlay.style.visibility = "visible";

window.setTimeout(function () {
    overlay.style.visibility = "hidden";
}, 5000);
```

You should take the following steps to achieve what you want:
1. The user loads the page.
2. The user receives a message from the server, stating that he is being synchronized
3. Then either after a specified time or after another message from the server you unblock the user
4. Finally you start the game

Comment: ok, but is a good solution to show I some div that will cover all screen 5s and then dissaper... so on css i will have a width:100%, height:100% and How I can change visibility on time etc. after 5s... so when 5s over then I change visibility:visible ... or hidden after some time???

Comment: Why exactly do you want to block user interaction for 5 sec? Then I can tell you if this is a good solution.

Comment: becouse I'm try to create some relatime app I need the perfect sincronization beetween users so all users to get div100% visibility:visible on same time

Comment: I trying to cretate somethin like simple game realtime multplayer and I need to know is better to do this with serverside code like I want, or just with clientside... becouse I need perfect sincronization beetwen users

Comment: or maybe i need a open connection with socket.io

Comment: That would be a possibility, yes. Then on the server you can do your synchronization tasks. Then on the client side you should inform the user of the synchronization process by displaying a message.

Comment: and so HOW to change css to div100% visibility: hidden or try after 5s? please if yoou can write on pastebin!

Comment: i know that... but sincroinzat that with server side

Comment: I want to server control the time not client becouse client can do the cheat

Comment: Just send messages to the client like you do in the other parts of your program and let the client side script react to them.

Comment: sorry but what exaclty I need to write on server side to this work. Please post on pastebin the code. THANKS A LOT!